# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent On install Apk

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager

I have a static function for Update my application, with downloadManager:

```
 public static void downloadApk(final Context context, String apkurl){
        String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        String fileName = "apk_update.apk";
        destination += fileName;
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

        //Delete update file if exists
        File file = new File(destination);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        //set download manager
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(apkurl));
        request.setDescription("...");
        request.setTitle("...");

        //set destination
        request.setDestinationUri(uri);

        // get download service and enqueue file
        final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

        //set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                installIntent.setDataAndType(uri, manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
                installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                ctxt.startActivity(installIntent); ////Error on here
                ctxt.unregisterReceiver(this);
               // ctxt.finish();
            }
        };
        //register receiver for when .apk download is compete
        context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

Error occurs after download complate on line :

```
    ctxt.startActivity(installIntent);
```

my error description:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=...

stack trace : [stack trace](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26279238/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId)
```

This is returning `application/mobile` as the MIME type. That is not a valid MIME type. Presumably, `DownloadManager` got this from the Web server from which you downloaded this content. If that is your Web server, fix it to use the proper MIME type for your content.

Comment: I changed to installIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");